# java web project in eclipse using relative path

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets, jakarta-ee

In a java **web** **project** in eclipse deployed in tomcat,here is the code snippet

```
File file = new File(".");
System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

and it prints out

```
D:\Program_Files\eclipse\.
```

which is the eclipse's root installation directory,I know that "." refer to a path means the path where java command runs,but why the path is `D:\Program_Files\eclipse\.`?
I found some other people test this code snippet,and they prints the path as `%tomcat_home%/bin`,how can I set to get the same code result of `%tomcat_home%/bin`?

Comment: Why do you need this? HINT: Obviously the current directory will vary depending on the environment: running Tomcat standalone, debugging with Eclipse, *running in production*. You should make your code independent of the exact location of the current directory.

Comment: @Nikos Paraskevopoulos Thanks for your advise, I just came across this difference from other people's code result and try to know what's the reason is,:)